# Aggregate function with DataTable in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, datatable

The `DataTable` may have the following structure and data.

```
Folder    User   P1 P2 P3
------------------------
FolderOne UserA  1  0  1
FolderOne UserA  0  0  0
FolderOne UserA  1  0  0
FolderOne UserB  1  1  1
FolderOne UserB  0  1  1
FolderOne UserC  0  0  0
------------------------

Result

FolderOne UserA  1  0  1
FolderOne UserB  1  1  1
```

I would like to get the above table as the result table. What operations should I do to get the desired result. ?

OR

Can I use LINQ here. Please note that the P1,P2, and P3 are `typeof(bool)`

The **logic** behind the result table is `group by` User Name and use `OR` operation for rows of P1, rows of P2, rows of P3. And there will be only one `FolderName`.

Comment: What are the logic behind result table?

Comment: What if there were other folders, and other users?

Comment: Why does your result table not show FolderOne UserC 0 0 0? What would happen if you had one user with two folder names? Please don't make us keep guessing at requirements.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Please See My Edit :)

Comment: @Rauf: If there'll only be one folder name, why bother including it at all? And you still haven't explained why there isn't a row for UserC.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know what you really need based on your description, but I'm going to guess. My first thought would be to remove the `DataTable` side, so we can work on a sequence of strongly-typed objects without `DataTable` getting in the way... which we can do like this:

```
var tableData = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(row => new {
                                     Folder = row.Field<string>("Folder"),
                                     User = row.Field<string>("User"),
                                     P1 = row.Field<bool>("P1"),
                                     P2 = row.Field<bool>("P2"),
                                     P3 = row.Field<bool>("P3")
                                 });
```

Then, taking a guess that you want to "OR" the results after grouping by folder and user, you could use:

```
var result = tableData.GroupBy(row => new { row.Folder, row.User })
                      .Select(g => new {
                                  Folder = g.Key.Folder,
                                  User = g.Key.Folder,
                                  P1 = g.Any(row => row.P1),
                                  P2 = g.Any(row => row.P2),
                                  P3 = g.Any(row => row.P3)
                              });
```

There may well be slightly more efficient ways of doing this, but I'd expect that to be pretty reasonable - and if you want more efficiency you should probably try to move the logic to whatever database query produces the table.

Comment: Is `dataTable` an object of `DataTable` ?

Comment: @AVD  And how can I convert the `result` to `DataTabel` ?

Comment: @Rauf: Do you really *need* it as a `DataTable`? What are you trying to do with the results? Personally I try to steer as far away from `DataTable` as possible...